# Development Kit doesn't provide Real-Time Access to Data

Tags: embedded, development

I have a development kit and an accelerometer from [Bosch](https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/bst/support_tools/downloads/overview_downloads), and I am using their Bosch Development Desktop 2.0.

Their development desktop allows me to save the data into a .txt or a .csv once the testing has been completed.  However, I am trying to pull the data in real-time, but their development desktop doesn't allow me to access the data during the course of my test.  Only after I stop the data collection do I have access to the file.

Aside from trying to find a different development kit and sensor from a different supplier - does anyone have any ideas about how to transmit the data in real-time (like, into Python or Matlab) so that I can run some algorithmic analysis on the data in real-time?

Comment: What kit? What data? To do what kind of job?

Comment: Have you asked the manufacturer? This would be my first stop.

Comment: You definitely need to ask the manufacturer.

Answer (score 2):

[The manual](http://manualzz.com/doc/7367488/development-desktop-2.0-user-manual), on page 16, section "5.3.2.1 Board communication" says you can configure the interface to be a COM port.

In principle, this means you can send and receive data using many different types of software and language.

I suspect the hard part will be working out the protocol they have used.